# Routing in Laravel 5 error

Tags: laravel-4, routes, upgrade, laravel-5

Routing in Laravel5 seems to be a major problem for me.

I was hoping to follow this example using the composer mapping

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5#namespacing-controllers

To avoid any issues with models or facades.

**But when I route to this**:

```
Route::get('school/test', 'school\SchoolController@index');
```

**Error**

```
    ReflectionException in Container.php line 776: Class school\SchoolController does not exist
```

The SchoolController is in the HTTP/controllers/school folder:

```
  namespace School
  class SchoolController extends Controller{
     public function index() {
        return "hello";
     }
 }
```

RouteServiceProvider:

```
 protected $namespace=NULL
```

composer is set for the HTTP/controllers

```
 "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models",
        "app/HTTP/Controllers"

    ]
```

and **works with routes such as this**:

```
Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController');
```

**So the router is just not finding files in a subfolder. I wonder what the problem is?**

It seems the only option is

```
 RouteServiceProvider

  protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Composer.json

```
  `"classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"        
    ],
```

HomeController in the App\Http\Controllers;

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Models\Course;

 class HomeController extends Controller {
 public function index()
 {
    $courses =Course::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('school')->paginate(12);

 }
```

**But this means I need to add 'use App/...'  for over 100 controller files, with varying models!**

I appreciate help so far but I'm really looking for method one if possible, as two will involve placing all the model maps in each controller (lots of code). Unless there is a global way to map all the models  in one file?

Someone suggested Alias but this doesn't work.

To re-iterate the issue. **Routing fails for Controllers subfolders using composer for mapping**

Comment: 1) It should be `namespace School;` - note the semicolon. 2) `SchoolController` should extend your base controller. 3) You're using `School` namespace in your class, however the route uses the lowercase version. Use the same namespace for both.

Comment: 1) There was just an oversight in my Q, sorry. 2) I was just simplifying I do have that in the code 3)tried that no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will by default search for controllers in `App\Http\Controllers`. You can change that namespace by editing `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

In your case, since you want no "base namespace" at all, set it to `null`:

```
protected $namespace = null;
```

---

1. Created directory structure: `app/Controllers/Folder` (the names don't really matter as long as they match with the rest)
2. Created controller in `Folder`: `TestController.php` (`namespace Folder;`)
3. Edited `autoload > classmap` in `composer.json` and added `"app/Controllers"`
4. Run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `app/HTTP/Controllers` ? That's where my controllers are stored by default in L5

Comment: It doesn't really matter

Comment: ok but I can follow your way with HTTP added in json and should work? `Route::get('test/one','Folder/TestController@index');`   `namespace Folder;
class TestController extends Controller {.....` Controller in HTTP/Controllers/Folder and json reflects this.

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure if the case is important so try to be exact and use `Http` not `HTTP`

Comment: It should be `Folder\TestController@index`

Comment: Yep,sorry typo. Still not working. But this works Folder_TestController though I fear there are other issues that will arise with this already had a facade error [link] http://www.laravelmy.com/2014/03/30/laravel-controllers-in-sub-folders-without-using-namespace/

Comment: I really have no idea what the problem is.. It seems to be an autoloading issue though. You can check if your file is listed in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

Comment: 'Folder\\TestController' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Controllers/Folder/TestController.php',

Comment: Looks correct to me. What error do you actually get?

Comment: It's finally worked!! With basic test anyway. Now just the other issues. But will mark you up for this. If interested I have another immediate issue, which will post now as new Q. Not so long hopefully!

Comment: If you can stomach it. Since you're in the frame and maybe quick [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715643/laravel5-extends-in-controller-in-subfolder