# Laravel5 extends in Controller in Subfolder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, directory, controllers

I have folder structure app/Http/Controllers/School inside which I have a SchoolController:

```
namespace School;
class SchoolController extends BaseSchoolController {.....
```

and BaseSchoolController:

```
namespace School
class BaseSchoolController extends \BaseController {....
```

(BaseController is in parent Controllers folder)

```
 class BaseController extends Controller {...
```

This gives an error:

```
    FatalErrorException in SchoolController.php line 5: Class 'School\BaseSchoolController' not found
```

Any ideas, thanks?

Seems happy with this structure though:

```
  class SchoolController extends \Controller {
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes, and the folders as I look are where they should be.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see right away, the namespaces are wrong.

Laravel 5 uses [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), which means that each namespace must match the folder structure (including the vendor) of a class file.

So, for `app/Http/Controllers/School/SchoolController.php`, the namespace should be set to:

`<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\School;`

not just

`<?php namespace School;`

Also, if the app name isn't the default one (`App`), change it accordingly on the namespace.

As an example, if you ran:
`php artisan app:name ACME`

the namespace should then be:

`<?php namespace ACME\Http\Controllers\School;`

Check other classes like `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`, to have an idea how it should be done.

Comment: nope you can use composer to keep your namespace structure.

Comment: In that case, you should also paste the relevant `composer.json` config, so that everybody knows what you're doing exactly. Otherwise, it all boils down to guess work.